# How are the argc and argv values passed to main() set up?

Tags: c++, c

I want to better understand what's going on under the hood with the command line arguments when a C or C++ program is launched. I know, of course, that `argc` and `argv`, when passed to `main()`, represent the argument count and argument vector, respectively.

What I'm trying to figure out is how the compiler knows to interpret `int argc` as the number of arguments passed from the command line. If I write a simple function that attempts to mimic `main()` (e.g. `int testfunc(int argc, char* argv[])`), and pass in a string, the compiler complains, "Expected 'int' but argument is of type char*" as I would expect. How is this interpreted differently when command line arguments are passed to `main()`?

Comment: The command line isn't passed in as a string, there are quite a lot of magic going on behind the scenes

Comment: C runtime startup code takes the argument string (from the OS, in the OS-specific manner), splits it into pieces, and calls `main` passing those pieces. Or in some cases (Unix-y systems) the OS (more precisely, the shell) parses the string and passes it in pieces to the C runtime.

Comment: Relevant: http://daviddeley.com/autohotkey/parameters/parameters.htm

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In common C implementations, `main` is not the first routine called when your process starts. Usually, it is some special entry point like `_start` that is provided by the C library built into your program when you link it. The code at this special entry point examines the command line information that is passed to it (in some way outside of C, particular to the operating system) and constructs an argument list for `main`. After that and other work, it calls `main`.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 2):

You don't pass `argc` value on your own (from the command line, for example), it is supplied by your environment (runtime), just like the *exact* content for `argc`.<sup>[Note below]</sup>

To elaborate, `C11`, chapter §5.1.2.2.1, (*indicators mine*)

> - The value of `argc` shall be nonnegative.
> - `argv[argc]` shall be a null pointer.
> - If the value of `argc` is greater than zero, the array members `argv[0]` through
>   `argv[argc-1]` inclusive shall contain pointers to strings, which are given
>   implementation-defined values by the host environment prior to program startup. The
>   intent is to supply to the program information determined prior to program startup
>   from elsewhere in the hosted environment. <sup>[Note start]</sup>If the host environment is not capable of
>   supplying strings with letters in both uppercase and lowercase, the implementation
>   shall ensure that the strings are received in lowercase.<sup>[Note end]</sup>